# PHP: Is there a way to loop through PHP annotations in another file?

Tags: php, annotations

Summary: I am trying to replace all the content in an html file between and including several sets of given tags.  For each set, the content is to be replaced with a specific chunk of code.  Because I have so many of these 'sets' of tags and their individual code, I have placed them in a **tags.php** file.  They are then called in my main **test.php** file by the `cf_replace()`;

Details:
In my **test.php**, I have a function that will replace content between two given start and end tags, with the content from another file.

```
include('tags.php');
$testFile = ('someFile.htm');

    function cf_replace($start, $end, $new, $file) {
    // stuff
    return $file 
    };

cf_replace($start_htmlHead, $end_htmlHead, $cf_htmlHead, $testFile );
cf_replace($start_header, $end_header, $cf_header, $testFile );
// etc.
```

In my **tags.php** file, I declare several variables:

```
/**
* @Marker
*/
    $start_htmlHead= '<!-- Start Html_Head -->';
    $end_htmlHead= '<!-- End Html_Head -->';
    $cf_htmlHead= file_get_contents( './cf_templates/cf_htmlHead.txt' );

/**
* @Marker
*/
    $start_header= '<!-- Start Header -->';
    $end_header= '<!-- End Header -->';
    $cf_header= file_get_contents( './cf_templates/cf_header.txt' );

// etc.
```

I've been having some trouble understanding the annotating markers, so I'm not sure how to use them correctly in (e.g.) a for loop.

Is there a way to loop through all the @Markers so that I can have a cleaner/less repetitive test.php file - that is, not have to keep writing out the `cf_replace()`??

Comment: Or is there a better way using arrays, even?  I was wondering if I can place each set in an array, but then I still run into using some sort of marker (e.g. the @ annotations...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot simpler if you just put your tag data into an array, then it can be iterated easily:

```
$tags=[
    ['htmlHead']=>[
      '<!-- Start Html_Head -->',
      '<!-- End Html_Head -->'
    ],
    ['header']=>[
      '<!-- Start Header -->',
      '<!-- End Header -->'
    ]
];

//test.php
include('tags.php');
$testFile = ('someFile.htm');

function cf_replace($start, $end, $new, $file) {
    // stuff
    return $file 
};

foreach($tags as $key=>$tag){
    $txtfile = file_get_contents( './cf_templates/cf_' . $key . '.txt' );
    cf_replace($tag[0], $tag[1], $txtfile, $testFile );
}
```

Comment: Wooooah!  That is so cool!  Is the $tags an array with...a few other arrays in it?  I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.  (Sorry, I'm a bit slow.)

Comment: Thank you, Steve.  That looks so much cleaner and more efficient. :]

Comment: @arl Yes, its an array of arrays (a multidimentional array). Note i didnt include the `cf_*.txt` data in the array because it looked like the file names followed a simple pattern, so could be generated when needed